# Best practice for k8s command health probe

Tags: kubernetes, readinessprobe

I have a worker pod that subscribes to a service queue. We need to define the liveness probe to monitor worker health. the worker pod doesn't expose any HTTP or TCP port. So I use the command to check worker health. like this.

```
  livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - cat
    - log/healthy-2020-07-16-03.log
```

Every 5s, worker pod will output health info to log file. logfile name format is healthy-YYYY-MM-DD-HH.log.
And each log info is like:

```
{"message":"Thu Jul 16 2020 03:23:30 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) health","level":"notice","Env":"local","Service":"myservice","timestamp":"2020-07-16T03:23:30.008Z"}
```

So I need to check the log timestamp and message for healthy.

My question is:

1. Is my approach follow the best practice of k8s health probe?
2. Does k8s support more powerful command? eg: python script or jq. I need to parse JSON and validate timestamp and message?
3. For worker pod, we don't need to define readiness probe, because it doesn't bind with k8s service or endpoint, right?

Comment: You may expose a tcp port exclusively to report liveness.

Comment: It is not necessary to expose TCP ports just for the sake of adding a liveness probe

Comment: @Malathi it's not necessary, but many times cheaper than to spawn several processes every few seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is my approach follow the best practice of k8s health probe?

Yes

> Does k8s support more powerful command? eg: python script or jq. I need to parse JSON and validate timestamp and message?

Actually, exec probe will be running as a command line inside the container. More details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#execaction-v1-core). So it is upto you to run anything like a python script or jq. However, you have to ensure that the command you are running in the probe can be executed inside the container. Say for example, you want to run a python script for the probe, ensure your container has python installed and the script also present inside the container.

> For worker pod, we don't need to define readiness probe, because it doesn't bind with k8s service or endpoint, right?

That depends on your use case and how your service works.

A nice article [here](https://medium.com/spire-labs/utilizing-kubernetes-liveness-and-readiness-probes-to-automatically-recover-from-failure-2fe0314f2b2e) explaining the readiness & liveness probe.

Comment: As I know, probe is executed by kubelet. kubelet is running on vm. I don't understand why command probe running inside container?

Comment: @Ruoxuan.Wang As mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#execaction-v1-core), 
`Command is the command line to execute inside the container, the working directory for the command is root ('/') in the container's filesystem. The command is simply exec'd, it is not run inside a shell, so traditional shell instructions ('|', etc) won't work. To use a shell, you need to explicitly call out to that shell. Exit status of 0 is treated as live/healthy and non-zero is unhealthy.`

Comment: Got it. So for http or tcp based probe, these runs on VM not container, right?

Comment: Hi, @Malathi. One more question, our worker service just listen Azure Event Hub(like Kafka). So do we need to define readiness probe?

Comment: May be before reading from the queue, your application can check if the service queue is reachable and fail otherwise. I don't think a readiness probe is necessary. Readiness probe is essential when your service receives traffic from other services or from outside the cluster.

Comment: I guess the http ad tcp probes are run from outside the VM. I am not sure though

Comment: It's a bad idea for readiness probe to rely on 3rd party resources.